# Replace every backslash to forward slash, javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Variable fileLocation may get two kinds of strings

1. `"N:\LDWG\PDF\2002P48.pdf"`
2. `"\\Gis1\GIS\LDWG\Pdf\2007P69.pdf"`

I just want result to be like

```
"N:/LDWG/PDF/2002P48.pdf"

"//Gis1/GIS/LDWG/Pdf/2007P69.pdf"
```

respectively

Tried

```
fileLocation.replace(/\\/g,"/")

str.replace("\\", "/")
```

But didn't work.

**Note: There is a double slash in 2nd string**

Comment: You must have double slashes in the strings, e.g.: `var s = "N:\\LDWG\\PDF\\2002P48.pdf"`. Then, the string will look like `N:\LDWG\PDF\2002P48.pdf`. Your `fileLocation = fileLocation.replace(/\\/g,"/")` will work.

Comment: `fileLocation.replace(/\\+/g,"/")`

Comment: Yeah, people were advising in other SO questions. But I don't how to do that, the data comes in that way. And also I wonder if it works for string, type 2 too

Comment: You need to assign the value to the variable `fileLocation = fileLocation.replace(/\\/g,"/")`

Comment: @Jai, It didn't work. Have a look at this  [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vipanth/wx5jLpsn/2/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Also require solution for `\\Gis1\GIS\LDWG\Pdf\2007P69.pdf`

Comment: You already have it. `"\\\\Gis1\\GIS\\LDWG\\Pdf\\2007P69.pdf".replace(/\\/g, "/")` (type this in the console, you will get `//Gis1/GIS/LDWG/Pdf/2007P69.pdf`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice, looks like it works. But how to add those extra backslashes for each

Comment: You have them if you read the strings from external source or get from a user, [your demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6vmm7ot3/) will work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Sorry, I didn't quite get that. All I found is that making `"\\Gis1\GIS\LDWG\Pdf\2007P69.pdf"` to `"\\\\Gis1\\GIS\\LDWG\\Pdf\\2007P69.pdf"` will solve my issue. How to get that. My variable will definitely be `"\\Gis1\GIS\LDWG\Pdf\2007P69.pdf"`like this initially.

Comment: Then there is no solution. The system you get strings from should do that.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I'll find a way out as suggested.